# Issues Starting JFrog in Docker

Tags: docker, jfrog-container-registry

I am trying to do

`docker run -d --name artifactory -v D://JFrog/artifactory/var/:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -p 8281:8081 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss`

By following this tutorial: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerComposeInstallation

However, even after setting permissions and adding `localhost` as `shared.node.ip`  in `$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml`

The logs are as follows from docker console: https://pastebin.com/dQAckECE

Any leads/help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: Are you running this on Mac?

Comment: No, Windows machine with a docker container, I have WSL2 enabled.

Comment: Try `docker.for.windows.localhost` instead of plain `localhost`

Comment: @gaganshera No luck with this as well

Comment: @MohitSharma can  you please set `shared.node.ip` to host IP and not local host?

Comment: I ended up removing the persistent volume and things started to work well